# React-Router - Link to the same page not triggering page unMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router Link` to navigate trough my SPA app.

In some cases I get a situation when there is a link from a page to the exact same page with the same parameters, for ex:

I am in `../page1/2` and I have a link to the same route:

```
<Link to='/page1/2'>
     click me
</Link>
```

My problem is that in this situation `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidMount` are not firing, only `componentDidUpdate`.

This is problematic because I need to do some cleaning in `componentWillUnmount`.

What is the solution?

Comment: There are two good answers here, but semanticly speaking, I think you should take @damianfabian 's answer. Adding an onClick would be better if you had to re-render your component based on a condition determined by the link, but in your case It seems you want to re-render it always. Again, both of them are correct, but `componentWillReceiveProps` is semanticly more appropiate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must check componentWillReceiveProps to handle this changes, react-router identify the component is active and don't unmount the component, just pass new properties.

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
   if(nextProps.id === this.props.id) {
     // Clean component and reload? 
   }
}
```

Comment: this will work, still have some question marks with this solution but thx

Answer (score 0):

`react-router` works like any other component - it triggers changes in state. If the state has changed, `react`'s reconciliation process will figure out what components (in your case, routes) will need re-rendering.

In your case, the page will be the exact same, which will make React think no change has happened. Therefore, the component will never re-render and never unmount.

The easiest solution would be to add an `onClick` handler to the `<Link />` that does your cleanup for you. Something like this:

```
handleCleanup(e) {
  if (window.location.href === e.target.href) {
    // do your cleanup like you do in componentWillUnmount
  }
}
render() { 
  return <Link onClick={this.handleCleanup.bind(this)} to={`/page/1/${this.state.someProp}` />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change only params and the same handler is rendered, the handler won't remount; it'll only be updated, just like children in React won't be remounted by changing their props (except key). So you don't get componentDidMount, but componentWillReceiveProps.

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
   // do whatever clean up you need before rerendering
   // goo practise checking somehow that you are in the desired situation
}
```

Anyway I suggest you to take a look to the [React Component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) that is really important if you are learning this framework.